# Placing items on a circles edge javascript

Tags: javascript, three.js, trigonometry

I am struggling to get the right formula for placing `n` items onto a circles edge. I have seen many examples but can't get the formulas to work in my code. I have also watched a couple vids on `cos, sin, tan` but it's not helping me get the right formula for what I want. I suck at math and am also new to js so this is twice as painful.

here is my code

```
for (let i=0;i<15;i++) {
  cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo, cubeMat);
  scene.add(cube);
    
   let angle = 2.1 * Math.cos(Math.PI/90);
   let x = 10 + Math.cos(angle) * 2 * (i - 1);
   let y =  10 + Math.sin(angle) * 2 * (i - 1);
    
    gsap.timeline({repeat: -1, yoyo:true})
    .to(cube.position, {duration:2, x: x, y: y});
  }
```

I would like to have all 15 items start in the middle and then evenly distribute in a circle during the animation. The above formulas are a Frankenstein of formulas I've found online trying to achieve my goal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you explain why you calculate your `angle` that way?

Comment: No clue. Saw it somewhere online and stuck it in. Like I said math isn't my strong point. I also tried just using 24 since 360/15 is 24, which I have also seen get used for this type of math. That didn't get my results either though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (I haven't tested it)...  The inline comments provide some basic explanations of the trigonometry...

Also, my understanding of THREE.js is that the cube will be initialized at position (0,0,0).  The code below is configured such that the cubes will spread out to a radius of 100 in the XY plane.

```
let n = 15;
let maxRadius = 100;

for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo, cubeMat);
  scene.add(cube);
    
  // Size of each slice is '360 / n' degrees or in radians '2 * Math.PI / n'...
  let angle = i * ( 2 * Math.PI / n );

  // Calculate 'x' distance as 'radius * cos ( angle )' and 'y' distance using 'sin'...
  let x = ( maxRadius ) * Math.cos( angle );
  let y = ( maxRadius ) * Math.sin( angle );
    
  gsap.timeline({repeat: -1, yoyo:true})
    .to(cube.position, {duration:2, x: x, y: y});
}
```

Comment: That's amazing. I haven't touched anything but basic +-*/ in years. I've got some learning to do and can use this to help. Thanks a ton!